# Calculate the following example.

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate following?

$$\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{5^{x+1} - 7^{x+1}}{5^x +7^x}$$

Comment: Divide the numerator & the denominator by (max$(5,7))^x$

Comment: Sir, I am not getting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{7^x.(5.(\frac{5}{7})^x - 7)}{7^x.((\frac{5}{7})^x +1)} $

$ = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5.(\frac{5}{7})^x - 7}{(\frac{5}{7})^x +1} $

$ = -7 $

Comment: I got it.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 7 = 5+2 thus $5^{x+1}-7^{x+1} = 5\cdot 5^{x}-(2+5)7^{x} = 5(5^x-7^x)-2\cdot 7^x$. Now you have the nicer expression if you put it into the nominator. 
\begin{equation} \dfrac{5^{x+1} - 7^{x+1}}{5^x +7^x}= 5\frac{5^x-7^x}{5^x+7^x}-2\frac{ 7^x}{5^x+7^x}\end{equation}
Can you solve it from here?

Comment: No, I am not get your answer...

Comment: The hint is correct but if the asker has problems seeing what is going on in the original expression, he will hardly see it clearer here.

Comment: @Joanpemo I disagree. The original expression contained terms of different exponents, while here we have all the same exponent which makes things nicer to look at, thus I believe this is a good hint as it does not sovle the exercise, yet makes it a bit easier. As no context was provide I did not want to give a full solution like corbah did.